# Update values based on the range they fall within?

Tags: excel

Column X:Z show data of zones and cost of living. I need to update those zones to populate the correct zone (column AC) value based on the number in column Z.

`county 1` falls within the zone 3 range of 112.6-117.5, so the column AA value for that row should show a 3, and so forth if the avg doesn't fall within the correct range.

I just want to find instances where the avg doesn't fall in the correct range based on values in column Y and column Z.

[image: table]

I figure this is a mixture of an index/if statement, but I can't figure out how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a lot easier if your Range table was like this:

[image]

In which case the following formula should work:

```
=MATCH(Z2,AD$2:AD$7,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change your range to include only the starting number, excluding the dash and the second number, you can use this formula:

```
INDEX(AC:AC,MATCH(Z2,AD:AD,1),1)
```

[image]